# jquery selector specificity and propagation

Tags: jquery

How can I prevent an previously defined event happening if there is one of a more specific one defined?

Here is an edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEHe/6/)

```
    <div class="first">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="click">click</span>
        <div class="second">
            <div class="wrapper"> 
                <span class="click">click</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  $('.first .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('first');
});

$('.second > .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('second');
});
```

I want the second span.click nested in the first div to not fire the event attached to the first div.

EDIT: (cheers for the down vote)

A couple of answers below work perfectly for the markup presented above using the direct parent > child selector. But unfortunately I've simplified the markup in the example which may have been misleading.

In my production code the click/button is part of a shared template that is used in both parts so the 'parent' selector in this example .second is several nodes up the DOM from the button.

I will try to add a more relevant fiddle.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEHe/1/) what you are looking for?

Comment: unfortunately the markup here is simplified and direct descendant selector won't work for the actual code.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle in the answer, have a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

Try in this way, using the *child selector* `>`:

```
$('.first > .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('first');
});

$('.second > .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('second');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `jQuery( "parent > child" )`, so your code now should be

```
$('.first > .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('first');
});

$('.second .click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('second');
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEHe/1/)

**Update**

Since you updated your markup, I have an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEHe/9/)